# What is this red shrub in my garden?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I've a plant growing in my garden, that I'm hoping somebody can identify.  I live in zone 5b or 6a, on the Plant Hardiness Zone Map.

It's about 2-3' tall, has dark red leaves,

[image: Red leaf]
[image: Leaf size]

gets little white flowers in the spring,

[image: White flower]
[image: Flower closeup]

and has a dark colored bark.

[image: Dark bark]

What is this plant?

Answer (score 8):

I reckon its Prunus cerasifera, or a cultivar of, commonly known as Purple Leaf Flowering Plum or Myrobalan plum. The leaves should be toothed or serrated at the edges - some varieties are more toothed than others, but I can see some of that on these leaves. I can't see inside a flower clearly, but there should be a reddish purple centre, or at least a darker eye, to the flower. Some of the varieties have red stamens initially, which I can see on one or two flowers. There should be a scent to the flowers - there are all white forms too. Hardy in zones 4-8.

Comment: Didn't initially mention it, but the shrub is only ~3' tall. Would that change your answer?

Comment: No - unless you know its been in situ for ten years and has never been pruned.

Comment: Missed the edit window, sorry - no, it wouldn't change my answer - some of the varieties are more spreading than tall anyway

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Prunus × cistena 'Crimson Dwarf'. To quote from the RHS, it's "an upright, bushy, medium-sized deciduous shrub with small, pinkish-white flowers. Leaves red-purple, deepening in the summer and brighter in autumn." If yours shows no sign of growing into a tree/large shrub, this is what it probably is.